# unable to use elementIsNotVisible with selenium webdriver for javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, promise

I'm unable to determine the non-existence of an element by using the `elementIsNotVisible` condition with the Selenium JavaScript Webdriver. The condition expects a webdriver.WebElement object but that is impossible as the element could already be disappeared from the page, resulting in an `NoSuchElementException`. Using `driver.findElement()` will not work as it returns an `WebElementPromise` object.

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(driver.findElement(By.css('div.bg-danger > div'))));
var element = driver.findElement(By.css('div.bg-danger > div')); // WebElement
driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(element)); // not a WebElementPromise
```

How can I solve my hair-tearing problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elementIsNotVisible` Creates a condition that will wait for the given element to be in the `DOM`, yet not visible to the user while you want to verify element exists in the `DOM` or not by given locator.

So you can't determine that element exists in the `DOM` or not using `elementIsNotVisible` because it supposed element to be in the `DOM` and now it's not visible.

`driver.findElement()` returns either element or `NoSuchElementException` so you can use this by handling the exception to determine element existence.

The best way to determine element existence try using `driver.findElements()` which returns either list of elements or empty list. So you just need to check it's length as below:-

```
var elements = driver.findElements(By.css('div.bg-danger > div'));
if(elements.length == 0) {
   console.log("element not visible");
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem for most part. I'm going to figure out how to do this with a Promise for polling. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.bg-danger > div")));
```

Comment: That would be the solution in Java indeed, but unfortunately the invisibilityOfElementLocated is not in the [JavaScript API] (http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html). The elementIsNotVisible is the closest equivalent I know of.